# xPath for varying node numbers

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to extract addresses using xPath from URLs like

https://www.americangemsociety.org/bradshaw-s-jewelers
https://www.americangemsociety.org/fincher-ozment-jewelers

etc.

However the problem is that the position of the addresses isn't uniform throughout the pages. Some of the pages have the address on Paragraph node # 4 while some others have them on Paragraph Node # 2 and so on.

I was wondering if I could use an xPath that identifies the addresses based on the 'strong class' of Address instead of a specific Node #

Example of an address within the HTML

```
<p><strong class="">Address:</strong> 4355 Montgomery Hwy, Ste 2, Dothan, Alabama 36303-1696</p>
```

Kindly advise

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use `//p[strong[not(normalize-space(@class)) and . = 'Address:']]` then you select all `p` elements which contain a `strong` element with contents `Address:`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, Martin. This worked perfectly.